# Custom layout for a field in Drupal 7 with using a term id and term name

Tags: theming, nodes

I have a content type that has term reference fields. One is a select one and one is a select many. What i'm trying to achieve is to overwrite the output for these fields.

I want the output of these 2 fields to be `<a href="../?selectedArtist={artistID}">{artistName}</a>` and `<a href="../?selectedLocation={locationID}">{locationName}</a>, <a href="../?selectedLocation={locationID}">{locationName}</a>`

These links will point to a page with an isotope grid layout on it, and will prepopulate the filters with what is in the querystring.

I have found how to update the output of the field, but I have no idea on how to get the terms ID and terms name.

```
function TEMPLATENAME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_artist') {
      $variables['items']['0']['#markup'] = '<a href="../?selectedArtist=">View Map</a>';
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at https://www.digett.com/insights/change-output-single-field-drupal-7-node I realised that you can use `$variables['element']['#items']`

**term id**
`$variables['element']['#items']['0']['tid']`

**term name**
`$variables['element']['#items']['0']['taxonomy_term']->name`